# CloudFormation Drift Analysis IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an IAM role that has had a policy manually attached to it giving it greater permissions than it should have.

I decided to run a drift analysis on the stack to which the role belongs to see if there were any other instances of manual change.

The results however do not show that this role has the extra policy attached despite [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) page saying that IAM roles are compatible with drift detection.

Is this something that should be picked up by CloudFormation?

Comment: CloudFormation (and Drift Detection) is extremely bad at detecting and more importantly fixing external changed to their resources. There is unfortunately not much you can other than writing a lot of custom code to detect and fix these changes which completely defeats the purpose of having an IaC tool in the first place. Just look at the "official" way of fixing a drift: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/implement-automatic-drift-remediation-for-aws-cloudformation-using-amazon-cloudwatch-and-aws-lambda/ (implement everything in python again)

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what's happening?

Comment: Haven't had time to check it properly yet, but managed policy sounds like it might be the way forward. Maybe I was just being a bit optimistic that it should have been able to work out the number of policies attached was greater than that in the template.
Will update when fully tested

Comment: No problem. How did your tests go?

Answer (score 2):

Drift detection is far [from perfect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html#drift-considerations). In terms of `AWS::IAM::Role` and policies it [works only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html#drift-considerations) when paired with `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy`. Otherwise, you observe what you find - no changes.